# viewDidLoad issue

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am having problem with ViewDidLoad Method.I have one .Xib File in my app and 5 viewControlelr.And Each View Controller Contains some initialization and method calls.

Problem is at the startup all the ViewDidLoad method runs.

Is there any way i can do this just when my ViewController will be called and the View is Loaded on the screen?

What is the proper way in this case?

I tried like this code :

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear
    {

    [ScoreWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://smwebtech.com/Pandit/web_service/getScore.php?u=aa"]]];

     }
```

But my program is not reaching this method.Why?Am i missing something?Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`viewWillAppear`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a) method instead. It is only called when the view is going to appear on screen.

Or [`viewDidAppear`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear%3a) which is only called after the view appears on screen.

EDIT:

Both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` take a BOOL argument each:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}
```

EDIT2:

These two delegate methods have their corresponding 'opposite' methods that you can override to release resources you allocate in the former methods:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [resource release];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [resource release];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: i am trying to use any one of the delegate method you mentioned.But They are not firing.Do you know why it's not working?

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju Make sure the delegate method accepts a BOOL argument: `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: how can i do that?I am have view controller class for all the views individually.And i want to load the views independently.

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju I don't understand your difficulties. In your question you wrote that all the view controller's `viewDidLoad` are called at the same time from when loaded from XIB, it's by design, there's nothing you can do about it. I'm giving you alternative that you just need to listen to `view appeared` event rather than `view loaded` event. This event is only triggered whenever a view appeared on screen thus it will be called one at a time for each view. And to listen to `view appeared` event, you just need to implement the `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { .. }` method.

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju Please see my update and compare with yours. I already mentioned and demo'ed that **the method needs to take a BOOL argument**. Is it that hard?

Comment: Thanks for the help.It's working..Can you please tell me how should i release the resources after closing the view?

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju You can use `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated { .. }` for that.